# Azure template to create public static IP address for each virtual machine

Tags: templates, azure, azure-resource-manager

I using the [CentOS-2nics-lb-cluster](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/CentOS-2nics-lb-cluster) azure template which generates a Load Balance and NAT Rule which enables a specific SSH port for each of
the Virtual Machines it creates.

My current ssh configuration look like

```
ssh admin@test01.cloudapp.azure.com -p 50000 // aka vm0
ssh admin@test01.cloudapp.azure.com -p 50001 // aka vm1
```

In my case, i really need to create a unique hostname for each of the virtual machines

```
ssh admin@test01vm0.cloudapp.azure.com -p 22
ssh admin@test01vm1.cloudapp.azure.com -p 22
```

Can someone suggest how i can change the template section below to achive this?

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
  "name": "[variables('lbName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "[variables('publicIPAddressID')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "backendAddressPools": [
      {
        "name": "BackendPool1"
      }
    ],
    "inboundNatRules": [
      {
        "name": "ssh0",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "frontendPort": 50000,
          "backendPort": 22,
          "enableFloatingIP": false
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ssh1",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "frontendPort": 50001,
          "backendPort": 22,
          "enableFloatingIP": false
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ssh2",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "frontendPort": 50002,
          "backendPort": 22,
          "enableFloatingIP": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "loadBalancingRules": [
      {
        "name": "LBRule",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "backendAddressPool": {
            "id": "[variables('lbPoolID')]"
          },
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "frontendPort": 80,
          "backendPort": 80,
          "enableFloatingIP": true,
          "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 10,
          "probe": {
            "id": "[variables('lbProbeID')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
```

Comment: A hostname per vm is what I need, and the ability to ssh in on the same port for each.

Comment: Actually ignore my previous comment, I was multitasking and misread what you're looking for! You can add additional IPs that would do what you are looking for, however I'm not sure how this is done via template. I would need to investigate a little to figure out the proper syntax -

Comment: Can you expand on the manual steps required to add an additional IP to a specific VM via the azure UI?

Comment: If you read through the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps/) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nmackenzie/54e9fe4bb34f8d6bce2e) there's probably enough to figure it out - its not something I've done before but I would imagine you would call `Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig` multiple times

Comment: @emeraldjava, does the answer below address your requirement? If it doesn't, please feel free to provide additional details. I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to each of your VMs with an unique hostname and same port, you would need to assign a public IP address to every VM. However, note that IPv4 public IP addresses are scarce and it is recommended to use NAT rules to access VMs behind a load balancer. Can you please provide additional context on why it is important to connect on the same port & unique hostnames?

In case this is absolutely needed, below is the relevant portion of a template to add a public IP address to a VM. You need to create a *publicIPAddresses* resource, and then assign it to a *NetworkInterfaces* resource which is then assigned to a *VirtualMachines* resource.

Take a look at the full template here, https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-sshkey/azuredeploy.json#L127

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
  "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
    "dnsSettings": {
      "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
  "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": {
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
          },
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[variables('subnet1Ref')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
      "linuxConfiguration": {
        "disablePasswordAuthentication": "true",
        "ssh": {
          "publicKeys": [
            {
              "path": "[variables('sshKeyPath')]",
              "keyData": "[parameters('sshKeyData')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
        "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
        "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
        "version": "latest"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "osdisk",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),'/', variables('osDiskName'),'.vhd')]"
        },
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
      }
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "diagnosticsProfile": {
      "bootDiagnostics": {
         "enabled": "true",
         "storageUri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```